# Do some investment banks make a spread by borrowing from the Fed at low rates and earning from higher Treasury and agency bond yields?

Tags: banking, federal-reserve

In his 60 Minutes interview for promoting his book, The Big Short, Michael Lewis [says](https://youtu.be/RnRGp2Ejcso?feature=shared&t=1106) this:

> if you look at their businesses right now they're heavily government  dependent that if you were uh goldman sachs or morgan stanley or jp morgan you have access  to a zero percent loan in virtually unlimited quantities from the federal reserve you can take  that money and reinvest it in treasury bonds or in in government agency securities and you will get  the spread and you could you could do it over and over you said he borrowed from the government lending the government taking out taking a cut

What facility is he talking about? I'm only aware of Fed's relationship with investment banks via OMOs. While conducting OMOs, the Fed buys government bonds from its primary dealers (the same investment banks Lewis is talking about) but I don't think that matches the spread he describes. Maybe it does and I'm not aware of how OMOs are conducted. Or is it that commercial banks lend investment banks at the FFR (or with only a small enough premium) who then buy government bonds offering higher yields?